# Using Plistbuddy to configure existing dict with a key and string

Tags: java, dictionary, plist, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to modify user Java settings.  I'm trying to set the security to `MEDIUM`.
Here is what I have so far, but it adds it as another `dict`.  I want to add it to the `/com/oracle/javadeployment/` key that exists already.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy \
 -c "add ':/com/oracle/javadeployment/:deployment.security.level:' string MEDIUM" \
 ~/Library/Preferences/com.oracle.javadeployment.plist
```

I end up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>/com/oracle/javadeployment/</key>
        <key>deployment.expiration.decision.10.51.2</key>
        <string>later</string>
        <key>deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.10.51.2</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>deployment.expired.version</key>
        <string>10.51.2</string>
        <key>deployment.log</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>deployment.modified.timestamp</key>
        <string>1399690282571</string>
        <key>deployment.version</key>
        <string>7.21</string>
    </dict>
    <key>deployment.security.level</key>
    <string>MEDIUM</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I would like

```
<key>deployment.security.level</key>
    <string>MEDIUM</string>
```

to be above the second to last `</dict>`.

I've tried moving around the `'` and `"` but I just get errors...

I tried to add a `0` in-between the keys and it adds it to the top of the `dict`, but also puts it inside its own `dict` and when this happens Java does not read the settings; it needs to be in the key `/com/oracle/javadeployment/`

Any suggestions?  I've been at it for a few hours and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing colon after deployment.security.level is the problem; it creates a dict.

Your command didn't exactly produce the results shown in your question, but I was able to get your output by using "add 'deployment.security.level' string MEDIUM" (which is also incorrect).

The following works for me on OS X 10.8.5:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy \
-c "add '/com/oracle/javadeployment/:deployment.security.level' string MEDIUM" \
~/Library/Preferences/com.oracle.javadeployment.plist
```

It yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>/com/oracle/javadeployment/</key>
        <dict>
                <key>deployment.expired.version</key>
                <string>10.21.2</string>
                <key>deployment.modified.timestamp</key>
                <string>1388446189200</string>
                <key>deployment.security.level</key>
                <string>MEDIUM</string>
                <key>deployment.version</key>
                <string>7.21</string>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```